# Python: getting a certain no. of strings from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, design-patterns

I have a dictionary in the following format, i split the different elements (where a comma(,) occured) using a split function and am now trying to extract the names from the list...i am trying to use regular expression but obviously am miserably failing being new to python... the names are in the following formats...

1. firstname(space)last name
2. name(space)name(space)name
3. x.name
4. x.y.name
5. name(space) x.(space)(name)

where x and y represent the an name initial like J. for john etc. 
also if you can guide me in removing the "\t" keeping other information intact would also be great. 
any sort of help would be more than welcome...thank you all.

```
[[' I. Antonov', ' I. Antonova', ' E. R. Kandel', ' and R. D. Hawkins. Activity-dependent presynaptic facilitation and hebbian ltp are both required and interact during classical conditioning in aplysia. Neuron', ' 37(1):135--47', ' Jan 2003.'], ['\tSander M. Bohte ', ' Joost N. Kok', ' Applications of spiking neural networks', ' Information Processing Letters', ' v.95 n.6', ' p.519-520'], [' L. J. Eshelman. The CHC Adaptive Search Algorithm: How to Have Safe Search When Engaging in Nontraditional Genetic Recombination. Foundations Of Genetic Algorithms', ' pages 265-283', ' 1990.'], ['Wulfram Gerstner ', ' Werner Kistler', ' Spiking Neuron Models: An Introduction', ' Cambridge University Press', ''], [' D. O. Hebb. Organization of behavior. New York: Wiley', ' 1949.'], [' D. Z. Jin. Spiking neural network for recognizing spatiotemporal sequences of spikes. Physical Review E', '69', ' 2004.'], ['Wolfgang Maass ', ' Christopher M. Bishop', ' Pulsed Neural Networks', ' MIT Press', ' '], ['Wolfgang Maass ', ' Henry Markram', ' Synapses as dynamic memory buffers', ' Neural Networks', ' v.15 n.2', ' p.'], [' H. Markram', ' Y. Wang', ' and M. Tsodyks. Differential signaling via the same axon of neocortical pyramidal neurons. Neurobiology', ' 95:5323--5328', ' April 1998.'], ['\t\tD. E. Rumelhart ', ' G. E. Hinton ', ' R. J. Williams', ' Learning internal representations by error propagation', ' Parallel distributed processing: explorations in the microstructure of cognition', ' vol. 1: foundations', ' MIT Press', ' Cambridge', ' MA', ' 1986 </a> \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'], ['\t J. D. Schaffer', ' L. D. Whitley', ' and L. J. Eshelman. Combinations of genetic algorithms and neural networks: A survey of the state of the art. In Combinations of Genetic Algorithms and NeuralNetworks', ' 1992.', ' COGANN-92. International Workshop on', ' pages 1--37', ' Philips Labs.', ' Briarcliff Manor', ' NY', ' 6 Jun 1992.'], ['\t S. Song', ' K. D. Miller', ' and L. F. Abbott. Competitive hebbian learning through spike-timing-dependent synaptic plasticity. Nature Neuroscience', ' 3(9):919--926', ' 2000.'], ['\t L. Watts. Event-driven simulation of networks of spiking neurons. Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems', ' 6:927--934', ' 1994.']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're going to have to tailor this pretty heavily to your input. Because there are so many different words and constructs in the text you're parsing, you're probably not going to get 100% accuracy with the rules you create. Here's an example, though, assuming your original input text is called `input_text` (and I don't think using the split() method is really all that useful, because the commas don't just delimit names):

```
import re

regexes = (r'[A-Z][a-z]+ [A-Z][a-z]+', # capitalized first and last name
           r'[A-Z]\. [A-Z][a-z]+')     # capitalized initial, then last name
names = []

for regex in regexes:
    names += re.findall(regex, input_text)
```

You'd obviously want to write additional specific regexes for your vaious name types. This does a good job of finding names, but also comes up with a lot of false positives (`Information Processing` looks a lot like a name based on these rules). This should give you a starting point though.

Comment: the above solution turned out to be quite helpful...i'd like to ask u something similar...but in a different context...the thing is that i had names in my list that were of the format... ['john a, smith,william tell,jacob oram'] now i wanted to correct the first name john a smith being one complete name but due to the format of the raw data it came out like this...now using the above method i found all such name using
ab=re.search((r'[A-Z][a-z]+ [A-Z]\,[A-Z][a-z]+'),zz[uy])
where zz[uy] is the location of the string...

Comment: now what i want is that i want is that i just want to replace the name in the correct format of john a. smith,william tell,jacob oram in the list...please help out

Comment: basically all that i want to do is replace the "," after "a" in john a, smith  with a  "." and place it back in the string

Comment: Why don't you ask this in a new question? Link it here when you do. That way others can jump in and help out too.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the tab (and other empty spaces at beginning or end of the strings):

```
stripped = [s.strip() for t in mylist]
```

To be honest, if you are trying to extract names, splitting lines like that will not help -- notice how some names are still grouped together with titles. Would be better to build a good regex that will match names, and use re.findall on individual lines.

Answer (score 0):

To remove tabs and extra spaces, use strip():

```
>>> "\t foobar \t\t\t".strip()
'foobar'
```

Answer (score 0):

It may also be, that its easier to find some online source of information where this job has been already done. For example, at places like [this](http://www.citeulike.org/user/eklypse/article/3179953) or [this](http://liinwww.ira.uka.de/bibliography/).

Answer (score 0):

1. strip all the strings
2. identify the string that are surely not names (very long ones, ones that include numbers, and one after these in the list)
3. indentify string that are surely names (short strings at the begining of the list, string starting by the pattern $[A-Z][a-z]{0,3}.?\s (Dr., Miss, Mr, Prof, etc)
4. sudy the last strings that you can't match with these rules, and try to make fuzzy rules to chose by creating a coefficient of certidude: the close to the beginin of the list, the shorter strings will have a hight score that something at the end with a big size. Add criterias like that and set a minimum score.

If you need a hight accuracy, loof for names database and bayesian filters.

It won't be perfect: it's very hard to know the difference between 'name name name' and 'word word word'